# What are the issues of running lightning daemon with pruning node?

Tags: bitcoind, pruning, lightning-network-daemon, core-lightning

Most lightning implementations I came across don't officially support pruned full node.

- Why is pruned mode implementation a challenge?
- What risk am I taking when I run lnd with pruned bitcoind?

Comment: [lnd v0.13.0-beta](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/releases/tag/v0.13.0-beta) now supports a pruned bitcoind backend

Answer (score 1):

Pruned nodes don't have the ability to make a full index of all transactions in the chain, which makes implementation of tools like Lightning difficult or impossible. There's no risk particularly, a pruned node has the same security properties as a normal one, it just doesn't have historical transaction data necessarily.

Comment: There is no reason that lightning should need access to a non-pruned node, and AFAIK c-lightning doesn't.  Regardless, any requirement for non-pruning is an implementation specific limitation.

Comment: "Notice that currently pruned nodes are not supported and may result in lightningd being unable to synchronize with the blockchain." from c-lightning README.

Comment: I was to mark this as accepted, but this has a downvote; I will wait for corrections.

Comment: c-lightning technically works with pruned nodes, the problem however is that if the node prunes the blocks before c-lightning was able to process them (for example by letting `bitcoind` run and `lightningd` is off for a long time), then c-lightning will not be able to catch up with the blockchain. If you can ensure that c-lightning is also running together with `bitcoind`, I see no problem with it and we have a number of users that are running it like this

Comment: The support mentioned in the readme is just to say that we don't want masses of people spamming the issue tracker with pruned node issues :-)

Comment: @cdecker are you saying that `bitcoind` has to be unpruned when first starting `lightningd` (i.e., bringing a lightning node online for the first time) and only *then* can `bitcoind` be told to prune?

Comment: Not exactly, `lightningd` will start syncing at the height that `bitcoind` is at the time of the first start (it'll not go back to the genesis block). It is only problematic if `bitcoind` is also syncing (since it'll outrun `lightningd` which will eventually end up in the pruned section of the blockchain) or ir `lightningd` is offline while `bitcoind` is making progress (also leaving `lightningd` in the pruned section and unable to catch up).